# Yii2 Display Recently Added Members

Tags: php, sorting, date, yii2

I have a "Latest Staff Members" panel where it should display my recently added users. All I have is a static display of these users:

```
<div class="box box-danger <?= !User::isBizAdmin() ? 'hidden' : '' ?>">
    <div class="box-header with-border">
      <h3 class="box-title">Latest Staff Members</h3>
      <div class="box-tools pull-right">
        <span class="label label-danger">8 New Members</span>
        <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
        <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.box-header -->
    <div class="box-body no-padding">
      <ul class="users-list clearfix">
        <li>
          <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/avatar-2/512/frank_man-128.png" alt="User Image"/>
          <a class="users-list-name" href="#">Alexander Pierce</a>
          <span class="users-list-date">Today</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/avatar-2/512/Ben_man-128.png" alt="User Image"/>
          <a class="users-list-name" href="#">Norman</a>
          <span class="users-list-date">Yesterday</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/avatar-2/512/iri_girl_face-128.png" alt="User Image"/>
          <a class="users-list-name" href="#">Jane</a>
          <span class="users-list-date">12 Jan</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/avatar-2/512/Jay_man-128.png" alt="User Image"/>
          <a class="users-list-name" href="#">John</a>
          <span class="users-list-date">12 Jan</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/avatar-2/512/Fred_man-128.png" alt="User Image"/>
          <a class="users-list-name" href="#">Alexander</a>
          <span class="users-list-date">13 Jan</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/avatar-2/512/michela_face_young-128.png" alt="User Image"/>
          <a class="users-list-name" href="#">Sarah</a>
          <span class="users-list-date">14 Jan</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/avatar-2/512/carla_girl-128.png" alt="User Image"/>
          <a class="users-list-name" href="#">Nora</a>
          <span class="users-list-date">15 Jan</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/avatar-2/512/hena_woman_face-128.png" alt="User Image"/>
          <a class="users-list-name" href="#">Nadia</a>
          <span class="users-list-date">15 Jan</span>
        </li>
      </ul><!-- /.users-list -->
    </div><!-- /.box-body -->
    <div class="box-footer text-center">
        <a href="javascript::" class="uppercase">View All Users</a>
    </div><!-- /.box-footer -->
</div>
```

Something like that. Now, in the `user` table in my database, I added a `date_added` column and I manually put dates in row.

Do I loop the data? Or use a widget? I don't know how else I should implement this.

**EDIT**

My controller:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest){
        return $this->render('../site/index');
    }
    else{  
        $latestStaffMembers = User::find()->orderBy(['date_added' => SORT_DESC])->limit(8);   
        return $this->render('dashboard', [
            'latestStaffMembers' => $latestStaffMembers,
        ]);
    }        
}
```

In my view:

```
<?php foreach ($latestStaffMembers as $user) { ?>
  <li>
      <img src="<?php echo $user->avatar; ?>" alt="User Image"/>
      <a href="#"><?= $user->username ?></a>
      <span ><?= $user->date_added ?></span>
  </li>
<?php } ?>
```

Then I get this error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

I tried var-dumping `$user` and it says `null`.

Comment: You could get a quick solution if you would generate controller, model and view with gii. You only need the table and all will be generated. After generation you would need to adapt things probably. At least you should have a model class extended from ActiveRecord.

Comment: hi. I already have a system and I have undergone those already. now I'm stuck with this problem.

Comment: Which problem do you have? Getting users from model? Displaying them in view? It should be only a metter of getting the appropriat user model objects and then displaying them with a loop or a GridView in view. Could you update your post to show us what you already have and what you are missing?

Comment: I am currently using admin-lte panel. In this [link](http://almsaeedstudio.com/preview), I am using the "Latest Members" panel. I changed mine to "Latest Staff Members". What I still have is the code I wrote in my question. Just that because I'm confused on how to display data (users) from the database in recent order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want. I hope it helps somehow.

In your controller action:

```
$latestStaffMembers = User::find()->orderBy(['date_added' => SORT_DESC])->limit(8)->all();
return $this->render('some-view-file', [
    'latestStaffMembers' => $latestStaffMembers,
]);
```

In your view:

```
<?php foreach ($latestStaffMembers as $user) { ?>
    <li>
        <img src="<?= $user->imagePath ?>" alt="User Image"/>
        <a class="users-list-name" href="#"><?= $user->name ?></a>
        <span class="users-list-date"><?= Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($user->dateAdded, 'd m'); ?></span>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
```

Btw: I saw `!User::isBizAdmin()` in your code. Is it yours? I would not just hide the list if it is important that only admins may see that. Just don't print it if user is not admin.

Comment: Thanks! Will be trying this now. And yes `!User::isBizAdmin()` is mine. Only BizAdmin users can see the "Latest Staff Members" panel.

Comment: I got this error `Trying to get property of non-object` in this line: `<span ><?= Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($user->date_added, 'd m'); ?></span>`

Comment: Hm... You may output `$user->dateAdded` directly, without date formatting (you can add this later). Is `dateAdded` the correct name of this property? $latestStaffMembers and then $user is set?

Comment: I tried editing `<?php echo $user->avatar; ?>` to something else because I got that error and I thought what I was doing was right but it wasn't and now `$user->dateAdded` has the same error `Trying to get property of non-object` and it's `date_added` not `dateAdded`

Comment: In your view you can use http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-vardumper.html to print some data of your variables. You can use it for $latestStaffMembers and $user to see if your view has got any users at all. What do you get? You could also update you post to show your controller...

Comment: Okay. And the view code is actually part of dashboard.php? And do you have foreach as well? Did you try out VarDumper?

Comment: hello. I have a question related to this one in the chat box.

Comment: I don't have that link anymore. What would you like to know?